# Mongoose: BSON field returns empty on model schema

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the folowing documents on MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5fddb4f404df1a32044f1f82"
    },
    "name": "1pc Chicken McDo with Spaghetti Meal",
    "description": "1pc Chicken McDo with Spaghetti Meal",
    " price ": 144,
    "image": "1pc-chicken-mcdo-with-spaghetti-meal.png",
    "locations": {
        "$regex": "[\"Angeles, Pampanga\", \"Baguio City\", \"Cabanatuan, Nueva Ecija\", \"Mabalacat, Pampanga\", \"Makati\", \"Mandaluyong\", Pasay\", Pasig\", San Fernando, Pampanga\", San Jose, Nueva Ecija\", San Juan\", Taguig\"]",
        "$options": ""
    }
}
```

Following that structure, I made this schema code on NodeJS. Notice that the last field which is `location` is declared as an array of flat String type.

```
var productSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  description: String,
  price: Decimal128,
  image: String,
  location: [{type: String}]
});
```

My problem is that everything else works when I try to retrieve the data using `find()` except for that `location` field. Here is an example of what the y model returns:

```
[
  {
    "location": [
      
    ],
    "_id": "5fddb4f404df1a32044f1f82",
    "name": "1pc Chicken McDo with Spaghetti Meal",
    "description": "1pc Chicken McDo with Spaghetti Meal",
    " price ": 144,
    "image": "1pc-chicken-mcdo-with-spaghetti-meal.png",
    "locations": {
      
    }
  },
]
```

As you can see, the location field remains empty despite everything else returning fine.

Can somebody help me figure this one out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a problem with escaping quotes and commas when importing from Excel to Compass. Advisable to do additional manual tampering with the converted data before doing the actual import. If you are able, use JSON instead of CSV just like as I did mine:

```
{
    "locations": [
      "Angeles,Pampanga",
      "Baguio City",
      "Cabanatuan,Nueva Ecija",
      "Mabalacat,Pampanga",
      "Makati",
      "Mandaluyong",
      "Pasay",
      "Pasig",
      "San Fernando,Pampanga",
      "San Jose,Nueva Ecija",
      "San Juan",
      "Taguig"
    ],
    "_id": "5fde0dd704df1a32044f1fde",
    "name": "1pc Chicken McDo with Spaghetti Meal",
    "description": "1pc Chicken McDo with Spaghetti Meal",
    "price": {
      "$numberDecimal": "144"
    },
    "image": "1pc-chicken-mcdo-with-spaghetti-meal.png"
},
```